# number of months in a table for each Individual value

Tags: sql

i have a problem with a sql query.
I have a table with shares which all have a lot of stocks but in the same table.

for example:

(there all in the same table):

```
**wkn - name - stock - date** <br>
12345 - Tesla - 200.92 - 2021.03.13
12345 - Tesla - 201.42 - 2021.04.14
12345 - Tesla - 203.59 - 2021.05.15
67890 - Amazon - 1002.33 - 2021.06.13
67890 - Amazon - 1005.34 - 2021.07.16
67890 - Amazon - 1012.99 - 2021.08.19
```

i want to have the number of the months where there is a value for a share for each one Individual.

for example:

> there are stocks for tesla for 20 months.

and heres the query that i tried. 
( the query is in a foreach loop ) 
( $value['wkn'] is each wkn Individual from the table )

```
$kurse1_monate= $this->_db->prepare("SELECT wkn, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, min(SELECT date WHERE wkn LIKE '" . $value['wkn'] . "'), max(SELECT date WHERE wkn LIKE '" . $value['wkn'] . "')) FROM kurse1 WHERE wkn LIKE '" . $value['wkn'] . "' GROUP BY wkn");
$kurse1_monate->execute();
$this->_kurse1_monate = $kurse1_monate->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: With ['wkn'] do you mean row or name ?

Comment: So thats the foreach loop:

Comment: foreach ($this->_wkn as $key => $value)

Comment: and wkn is quasi each name Individual

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write something i think would atleast get a good idea of what i meant. Not the best at sql but i think its readable.

```
SELECT [months] = FLOOR(A.[currentstock] / (stockdiff / monthdiff))
    FROM (
        SELECT monthdiff = DATEDIFF(MONTH, min(date), max(date)) 
            , stockdiff = max(stock ) - min(stock)
            , currentstock = min(stock) 
        FROM kurse1 WHERE wkn LIKE 12345 GROUP BY wkn
    ) A
```